# how can I check whether or not a user has logged in

Tags: jsp, web-applications

Please help me on my final year project; online question and answer site.  With this site, any user can search for a question and see the answer.  To ask a question, the user must first login.  my problem is this: how can I check whether or not a user has logged. Can it be done using session control?  Please help.

Comment: how?if the user don't login then how can i create session?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when the user is logged in, the site sends a cookie, which the browser stores. In each subsequent request the browser sends that cookie so that the site can verify whether th user is logged.

Normally, there are two cookies:

- the session cookie (called JSESSIONID), which is set whenever the server starts a session. Note that even non-logged users (can) have a server-side session.
- the logged user cookie, which stores some identifier about the logged user. For security reasons you should not store the user id, or worse - his username and password. Store some token that is invalidated on each login. (In fact, you can store 2 cookies, but this strategy is beyond the scope of this answer).

Comment: plz elaborate. if the user does not login then how can i get session?

Comment: what will be the data type session or vector i mean like this session s= request.getSession(["sessionnsme"]);

Comment: that you can see in the API docs. The Session is sort-of a map that has key-value entries.

Comment: i don't know all these things. can you understand my prob. i want to do this just like answers.com. there to post a question a user must login first.. just help me in a simple way

Comment: well, your question was rather general. I explained the general situation. If you want something concrete - check some tutorial. There are plenty.